# Check Masked Text Box is empty or not VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, maskedtextbox

I have Masked Text Boxes in my form. One is for salary, PF&ESI and Other is for Phone Number. I try to check the Masked Text Box is empty or not with following code.

```
Dim mtxt As Control
Dim flag3 As Boolean
flag3 = False
For Each mtxt In EMPGBDATA.Controls
    If TypeOf mtxt Is MaskedTextBox  Then
        If mtxt.Text = "" Then
            mtxt.BackColor = Color.Red
            flag3 = True
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Only my salary, PF&ESI Masked Text Box show in Red color, But Phone number Masked Text Box is not show Red.

Comment: Incidentally, both `mtxt` and `flag3` are truly horrible names. Please use meaningful names and proper indentation to make your code readable. Furthermore, do not declare your variables before using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the following situation: (Probably defined by the property designer)

```
 maskedTextBoxPhoneNumber.Mask = "000000 00000"  'Or something similar'
 maskedTextBoxPhoneNumber.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals
```

in this case your test for

```
 if mtxt.Text = "" then
```

will fail because the literals included in the mask property are returned in the property `Text`

you should change the property `TextMaskFormat` to

```
 maskedTextBoxPhoneNumber.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals
```

[See MSDN for MaskFormat Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskformat%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: RichTextBox is really a different control. Multiline, RTF Text, Block Formatting and other more complex properties. No mask or TextMaskFormat. So I really can't give any useful tips without knowing your intentions.

Comment: Friend.. I mean is there any chance to check the Rich Text Box is empty, if empty its Back color show red with same code i given above with my question..

Comment: This should be simple to try. Add another test _(if Typeof mtxt Is RichTextBox Then)_